# Nuxtjs auto log out user inactive

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxtjs for my project. I need to logout the user if there is not active after a given time frame. I'm creating a new component name autologout.vue and add this code to it

autologout.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    hello
    <div v-if="warningZone">warning</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      events: ['click', 'mousemove', 'mousedown', 'scroll', 'keypress', 'load'],
      warningTimer: null,
      logoutTimer: null,
      warningZone: false,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.events.forEach(function (event) {
      window.addEventListener(event, this.resetTimer())
    }, this)

    this.setTimers()
  },
  destroyed() {
    this.events.forEach(function (event) {
      window.removeEventListener(event, this.resetTimer())
    }, this)
    this.resetTimer()
  },
  methods: {
    setTimers() {
      this.warningTimer = setTimeout(this.warningMessage(), 4 * 1000)
      this.logoutTimer = setTimeout(this.logoutuser(), 10 * 1000)

      this.warningZone = false
    },
    warningMessage() {
      this.warningZone = true
    },
    logoutuser() {
      this.$auth.logout('local').then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
      })
    },
    resetTimer() {
      clearTimeout(this.warningTimer)
      clearTimeout(this.logoutTimer)
      this.setTimers()
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style></style>
```

add import this component to layout->default.vue. I'm not using default.vue layout to my login page. after I'm login and redirect to the home page it always logout me. What is wrong?

I'm using this tutorial to implement this

[Tutorial link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7TVcxOD4uh0)

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not a perfect way to handle the problem, but if you remove the parentheses present inside the *addEventListener* function, it will start working.

Change

```
window.addEventListener(event, this.resetTimer())
```

To

```
window.addEventListener(event, this.resetTimer)
```

And if you remove the paratheses from *removeEventListener*, it will again stop working. Don't know why.

Comment: wind.addEventListener accepts the event name and a handler function. By removing the parentheses you are passing a function. If you add the parentheses back, you are no longer passing a function, instead the function is evaluate - in this case the result will be `void` instead of a function.